# Residual plot like method to check if linear model applicable for Multiple Linear Regression

Tags: python, machine-learning, regression, data-science

For a simple regression model, we can use residual plots to check if a linear model is suitable to establish a relationship between our predictor and our response (by checking if the residuals are randomly spread out).

However, is there a similar method to check if linear regression is applicable when we have multiple predictors and one response (i.e. for a multiple linear regression model)?

Comment: A histogram of the regression errors should show an approximately normal distribution.

Answer (score 1):

The same intuition applies in the case where you have multiple predictor variables. (You could search either on "multivariate" or "multiple" regression, since people tend not to agree on when to use which term).

A quick statement of the theory is this: you want to "partial out" the effects of other predictors on the response in order to see the effect of *just* the predictor of interest. To do this, you have to first isolate the effect of any predictors aside from the one you've chosen (via regression, naturally), then get the residuals. But since you need to understand the effect all the other predictors have on the one you're interested in, you must perform a regression of the variable of interest against all the rest, from you get a second set of residuals. Plotting these against each other shows some information about the possible (non-) linearity of the relationship between your response and your variable of interest.

More concretely, consider a regression equation with two predictors and an intercept:

`y = x_0 + x_1*B_1 + x_2*B_2 + u`

Say we want to get partial residuals for `x_1`. First, regress `y` on `x_0` and `x_2`. This will give you a fitted `y` that does not include `x_1`, obviously. This gets you the portion of `y` that is not predicted by `x_1`; lets call that `y^`. Now you need to get the residuals from that regression: `y* = y - y^`.

But you will then need to estimate the effect the other predictors have on the one of interest. In this case, you need to regress `x_1` on `x_0` and `x_2`. This is the amount of `x_1` that is predicted by the other variables; call that `x_1^`. Similar to the response residuals, get `x_1* = x_1 - x_1^`.

Now, just plot `y*` against `x_1*` to see the relationship.

[This page](https://www.itl.nist.gov/div898/software/dataplot/refman1/auxillar/partresi.htm) might be a good reference for you.

In python, the `statsmodels` package has a `plot_ccpr` function that will plot partial residuals along with a fitted line. A full description is [here](https://www.statsmodels.org/stable/generated/statsmodels.graphics.regressionplots.plot_ccpr.html).